# Is it possible to declare a scanner variable inside a method in Java to read keyboard input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
final int MAX_ROUNDS = 5;
String name1,name1;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter player1 name: ");
name1 = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter player2 name: ");
name2 = keyboard.nextLine();
Player player1 = new Player(name1);
Player player2 = new Player(name2);

Dealer dealer = new Dealer();

    for(int count = 1; count <=MAX_ROUNDS; count++)
    {
        System.out.println("------------------");
        System.out.ptintf("Round : %d",count);
        dealer.rollDice();
        player1.makeGuess();
        player2.makeGuess();
        roundResults();
```

excerpt from the makeGuess method which belongs to the  Player class.

```
public void makeGuess()
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)

System.out.printf("Please guess 'even' or 'odd' "+
        "%s.", name);
String answer = keyboard.nextLine();

        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("even")
            guess = "Cho (even)";
        else
            guess = "Han (odd);
  }
```

I am not being prompted anything when the method executes I cannot understand why I did not include everything for the program. was just wondering if anyone eye balling this code could see something obvious otherwise, i will just take out the guess submission.

Comment: Are you sure that you're running something that has compiled?  In the makeGuess function, there is a missing ) to the if that checks the answer.

Comment: In any case, you shouldn't be creating a Scanner in every method. Create a Scanner once and pass it as a parameter to methods that need it.

Comment: yes i fixed the missing curly brace before program execution. So in these situations i should pass a Scanner object to the method. I would only need one import statement then in my main class and create the object in my main method then pass it to the makeguess method right. thank yall for the help with stuff. still doesnt doesnt prompt me for input im gonna try a few things.

Comment: okay i figured it out. i had two player classes on my net beans created one was the one i modified for the input and the other was using  random numbers to generate the player guess. my mistake i knew something was weird thank yall

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot find anything wrong with your code, If I had to take an educated guess, the dealer.dice() method probably has an infinite loop, which is causing your whole program to malfunction

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to print out name1, name2, etc. variables that get their values from the scanner to see if it is working? Try doing that immediately after setting their value to be keyboard.nextLine(). This should then give you a better idea of where the problem lies.

Comment: i figured out the reason i wasnt getting the expected results from makeGuess(). i had two player classes  and the main method program i was working on happen to be refereing to the other player class/makeGuess(). so i was updating make guess but nothing happening. i fixed it, it works now. and learned how to just past Scanner object as a prameter instead of creating a new one.